# Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, dll, jansi

Hi Guys I recently got an error when I'm doing the "mvn clean install" for my project 
can someone help me, please!!!

Here is the error I'm facing.

Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path, Native Library C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-64.dll already loaded in another classloader]

Detailed:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no
>   jansi in java.library.path, Native Library
>   C:\Users\ypava\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-64.dll already loaded in
>   another classloader]  at
>   org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:184)   at
>   org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:142)     at
>   org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32.(Kernel32.java:37)     at
>   org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream.(WindowsAnsiOutputStream.java:52)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.getOutputStream(ConsoleAppender.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.getDefaultManager(ConsoleAppender.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.createDefaultAppenderForLayout(ConsoleAppender.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.setToDefault(AbstractConfiguration.java:571)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.(DefaultConfiguration.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.(LoggerContext.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
>     at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
>     at
>   com.disney.wdat.api.roompricing.facade.impl.WDWSeasonalPriceDAOFacadeImpl.(WDWSeasonalPriceDAOFacadeImpl.java:21)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:43)   at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:152)    at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:122)     at
>   javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:78)  at
>   com.disney.wdat.api.roompricing.facade.impl.WDWSeasonalPriceDAOFacadeImplTest.setup(WDWSeasonalPriceDAOFacadeImplTest.java:37)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)

Comment: You can't load the same native library more than one time. if it is the case load it once and expose your interface to classes that need it

Comment: Solved this by adding a maven dependency

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>